# Rails grape swagger Array example value is showing as an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

I have a nested array on my rails grape api.

```
expose(
      :users,
      documentation: {
        type: Array,
        desc: 'The pickups and deliveries for specific tours'
      },
      using: Fleetdog::Entities::Users
    )
```

But when I visit the api-docs page the example value is a hash not an array.

```
example value
{ id: 'string',
users: {
  id: 'string',
  name: 'string'
}
```

Is this how grape supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

After exploring [sources](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-swagger-entity/blob/f001b87d0140301b4ea5f13aff2203afec0c79ba/lib/grape-swagger/entity/attribute_parser.rb#L22) I've found option `is_array` and it works:

```rb
expose(:projects, documentation: { type: Fleetdog::Entities::Project,
                                   is_array: true,
                                   desc: 'Projects' }) do |query|
  Fleetdog::Entities::Project.represent(
    Queries::Projects.call(query: query)
  )
end
```

=>

```json
"projects": [
    {
      //...
    }
  ]
```